# PHP Multiple Checkbox Array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, checkbox

I've looked around for a few examples here but a lot of them are either too advanced for my grasp of PHP or their examples are too specific to their own projects. I am currently struggling with a very basic part of a PHP form.

I am trying to create a form with a few checkboxes, each assigned a different value, I want these to be sent to a variable (array?) that I can echo/use later, in my case I will be sending the checked values in an email.

So far, I have tried a few variations, but the closest I have come to it is this...

```
<form method='post' id='userform' action='thisform.php'>
<tr>
    <td>Trouble Type</td>
    <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar' value='Option One'>1<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar' value='Option Two'>2<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar' value='Option Three'>3
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type='submit' class='buttons'>
</form>

<?php
$checkboxvar[] = $_REQUEST['checkboxvar'];
?>
```

Where I'd echo $checkboxvar[] into my email.
Am I going about this completely wrong? The other idea I had was to use a lot of if statements.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
<form method='post' id='userform' action='thisform.php'> <tr>
    <td>Trouble Type</td>
    <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option One'>1<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Two'>2<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Three'>3
    </td> </tr> </table> <input type='submit' class='buttons'> </form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['checkboxvar'])) 
{
    print_r($_POST['checkboxvar']); 
}
?>
```

You pass the form name as an array and then you can access all checked boxes using the var itself which would then be an array.

To echo checked options into your email you would then do this:

```
echo implode(',', $_POST['checkboxvar']); // change the comma to whatever separator you want
```

**Please keep in mind you should always sanitize your input as needed.**

For the record, official docs on this exist: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Comment: I think I'm getting it, but I'm really new at this and having trouble understanding how I can use `implode(',' $_POST['checkboxvar']);` to put it into my email. Currently I have `$message = "Message blah blah $array. \n";` but it doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: @DarekGajda `$message = "Message blah blah " . implode(',', $array) . "\n";` the comma within the quotes `','` replace with whatever separator you want, if you want it separated with a space put `' '` etc.

Comment: @DarekGajda remember please sanitize your input so as to prevent mail header injection attacks. Basically do `$array = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), ' ', $array);` to strip out newlines and carriage returns.

Comment: what if we want to get and send the text inside tags as well? like this 1,2,3.

Answer (score 23):

add `[]` in the name of the attributes in the input tag

```
 <form action="" name="frm" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="coding">  coding &nbsp
<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="database">  database &nbsp
<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="software engineer">  soft Engineering <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

for PHP Code :

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']){
   $hobby = $_POST['hobby'];

   foreach ($hobby as $hobys=>$value) {
             echo "Hobby : ".$value."<br />";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: His includion of the foreach statement has been very helpful for my situation. Thanks, Rawnay.

Comment: @Sébastien Anybody can add answer if OP accepted an answer it doesn't mean that it is the best answer;

Answer (score 5):

Try this, by for Loop

```
<form method="post">
<?php
for ($i=1; $i <5 ; $i++) 
{ 
    echo'<input type="checkbox" value="'.$i.'" name="checkbox[]"/>';
} 
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="form-control" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $check=implode(", ", $_POST['checkbox']);
    print_r($check);
}     
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the square brackets notation to have values sent as an array:

```
<form method='post' id='userform' action='thisform.php'>
<tr>
    <td>Trouble Type</td>
    <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option One'>1<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Two'>2<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Three'>3
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type='submit' class='buttons'>
</form>
```

Please note though, that only the values of only checked checkboxes will be sent.

Comment: When I try to call upon checkboxvar[] it simply returns "Array" instead of the values assigned to the checkboxes.

Comment: @DarekGajda please see my answer on how to echo it out.

Answer (score 3):

Also remember you can include custom indices to the array sent to the server like this

```
<form method='post' id='userform' action='thisform.php'>
<tr>
    <td>Trouble Type</td>
    <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[4]' value='Option One'>4<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[6]' value='Option Two'>6<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[9]' value='Option Three'>9
    </td>
</tr>
<input type='submit' class='buttons'>
</form>
```

This is particularly useful when you want to use the `id` of individual objects in a server array `accounts` *(for instance)* to send data back to the server and recognize same at server

```
<form method='post' id='userform' action='thisform.php'>
<tr>
    <td>Trouble Type</td>
    <td>
    <?php foreach($accounts as $account) { ?>
        <input type='checkbox' name='accounts[<?php echo $account->id ?>]' value='<?php echo $account->name ?>'>
        <?php echo $account->name ?>
        <br>
    <?php } ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<input type='submit' class='buttons'>
</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['accounts'])) 
{
    print_r($_POST['accounts']); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

for($i = 0; $i<= 3; $i++){

    if(isset($_POST['books'][$i]))

        $book .= ' '.$_POST['books'][$i];
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.