# Checkboxes in PHP using an array

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have an assignment that requires me to create two mock music services, each with a small library of songs available for purchase.  If I can figure out how to make one work, the rest should be simple for the most part.  I managed to get checkboxes working ONCE in my file but I modified one thing VERY SLIGHTLY and now the whole thing refuses to work.  What I need to know is how to generate several checkboxes using a text file (which I put into an array), save the selected choices, and put that into a new text file to be read by another .php thing.  This is what I have so far.

```
<html>
<?php
//Get contents from zmzonSongs.txt file, put into array.
$songList = explode("\n", file_get_contents('zmzonSongs.txt'));

//Print songs to be selected.
foreach($songList as $songs){
    echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name=\'$songList[]\' value='$songs />$songs<br>";
}
?>

</html>
```

I need help immediately.  The assignment is due soon and I'm struggling to make this work.  I need to make it so that the contents of the array can be written into some file after whichever songs the user wants are selected.

Comment: .....value='$songs <<<<< You are missing an end quote here

Comment: I tried fixing that just now and it didn't solve anything.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array

Comment: Alright, I just managed to get the checkboxes working again.  Apparently I didn't change the permissions on it or something but now I need to know how to move everything that was checked into a text file, line by line.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your name="$songList[]" doesn't need the $.

When sending check boxes from an HTML form to PHP array it is not required in my experience.

```
foreach($songList as $songs){
    echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='$songs' />$songs<br>";
}
```

Comment: also those escapes around the name= are unnecessary.

Comment: The one time I managed to make the thing work, it had the escapes.  I tried running it almost immediately afterward and nothing showed up on the page.

Comment: Double-quoted strings don't need concatenation for variable interpolation; single-quoted strings do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$songs = explode("\n", trim("
Song #1
Song #2
Song #3
Song #4
Song #5
Song #6
Song #7
"));

print_r($songs);

while ($song = array_shift($songs)) {
    $song = trim(htmlentities($song));

    echo "
<input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='$song'/> $song
";
}
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Song #1
    [1] => Song #2
    [2] => Song #3
    [3] => Song #4
    [4] => Song #5
    [5] => Song #6
    [6] => Song #7
)

<input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='Song #1'/> Song #1

<input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='Song #2'/> Song #2

<input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='Song #3'/> Song #3

<input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='Song #4'/> Song #4

<input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='Song #5'/> Song #5

<input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='Song #6'/> Song #6

<input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='Song #7'/> Song #7
```

http://codepad.org/fK187pfz

And the file saving bit:

https://www.php.net/function.file-put-contents

```
if (is_array($_POST['songList'])
     && !empty($_POST['songList'])) {
    $songList = implode("\n", $_POST['songList']);
    $songList = filter_var($songList, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    file_put_contents($songList, '/your/path/to/directory/songList.txt');
}
```

If you want to remove all songs, I'll leave that to you to work out. However, I would suggest you have a `name` attribute on your `submit` button...

Your instructor probably wants you to do the `fopen()`/`fwrite()`/`fclose()` process, though, so I would check the PHP manual for examples how to do that.

Comment: I have ten songs in a .txt file and the code is meant to be more universal in the event that more songs are added to the text file.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Replace the string within the `explode` with your call to `file_get_contents()`. codepad doesn't allow that function, so I can't demonstrate that. You also probably want to add `<br>` to the end of the `echo`'d line.

Comment: I would probably also use a `label` around it so it's easily clickable: http://codepad.org/GkhzIzUu Note as well I used `$song` instead of `$songList` for the row variable, since you get a `song` from a list of `songs`, and then the *checklist* that's selected is an actual `songList`. Properly naming your variables helps keep things from getting confusing.