# creating multiple checkboxes using a while loop in php and html

Tags: php, html, checkbox

im trying to create multiple checkboxes in html using a while loop in php.

```
while($counter != 5){

?>

<Input type = 'Checkbox' Name = '<?php echo '$foods[$counter]'; ?>' value ="yeeeey">

<?php 

echo $foods[$counter];
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 

 ?>

<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" name="<?php echo $foods_val[$counter]; ?>"
onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" style="width:55px";>
<P>

<?php

$counter++;
}

$counter = 0;

?>

<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Input order">
</FORM>
```

just dont mind the text field for now. basically, im trying to create multiple checkboxes with their name and value based on an array.

```
$foods = array($rw, $mrd, $rd, ... , $bb);
```

and each of those variables contains a string.
i have a code to detect which checkboxes were checked

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit1'])){
    while($counter != 21){
        if(isset($_POST['$foods[$counter]'])){
            echo "yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeey";
        }
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

however, when i try checking some boxes, the string "yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeey" is never printed. it seems that $_POST['$foods[$counter]'] is empty even when it is supposed to contain "yeeeeeey". how do you solve this? sorry for crappy formatting, still getting used to it. thanks

**small update. all variables inside $foods[$counter] now contains the same string: "food". my problem now is that all checkboxes behaves as if they were checked and contains the same value "yeeey"**

Comment: Do you find that anything is set? What happens if you put an `echo` just inside the `if(isset)` statement; what if it's just inside the `while($counter)` statement? Basic debugging should precede asking on SO.

Comment: im still new to php so your "basic debugging" may not be basic for me, sorry

Comment: What I mean is: you can put lots of `echo` commands in your script, so you can see the value of variables at every pass through the loop. This usually teaches you a lot about your program, and why things aren't working. Using a name with `[]` generates an array of checkboxes; see @IamManish's answer, or see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14026375/1967396 for a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code to generate array of check box through php.

---

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while($i < 5) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='hobbies[]' />";
        $i++;
    }
```

---

This code will create array of 5 checkbox...you don't need to specify counter variable like 
you did...

```
<Input type = 'Checkbox' Name = '<?php echo '$foods[$counter]'; ?>' value ="yeeeey">
```

Comment: so what will be the value of hobbies[]? new to php sorry

Comment: $hobbies[0] = yeeeey; $hobbies[1] = yeeeey; $hobbies[2] = yeeeey; $hobbies[3] = yeeeey; $hobbies[4] = yeeeey;

Answer (score 1):

I think, your problem is at least related to the quotes you're using in `$_POST['$foods[$counter]']`. If you use "double quotes", PHP variables beginning with $ are replaced by their value, but if you use 'single quotes', they are not. So you're trying to access the key `'$foods[$counter]'` (literally!) of `$_POST`.

Replacing them by "double quotes" may work, but since `$foods` contains strings, you don't need the quotes at all: `$_POST[$foods[$counter]]`

If that still doesn't work, there probably are some more flaws in your code. For the moment, give this a trie ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" name="food_vals[]" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" style="width:55px";>
```

Then on the server side:

```
foreach ($_POST['food_vals'] as $value) {
     echo $value;
}
```