# How can group a form's checkboxes into an array in Node?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am trying to create a form with several checkboxes. I want each checkbox to share the same name, and the values of the ones checked off to be submitted with the form. I know that this can be done with PHP (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array)) but I can't figure out how to do it with Node.js and Express. Here's a modified version of my HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="section[]" value="1" />Item Name</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="section[]" value="2" />Item Name</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="section[]" value="3" />Item Name</label>
```

When I handle the POST request, I've tried accessing the values with both `req.param('section')` and `req.param('section[]')` but they both return undefined.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also posted your code. Different body parsing modules can parse form data differently.

Comment: I am using [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

Comment: The whole codebase is on github, the parsing code is around [line 102 of this file](https://github.com/gregthegeek/JGrader/blob/master/JGrader/routes/teacher.js#L102).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you change this line in your `app.js`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

to:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

you should get what you are expecting with `req.param('section')`.