# Show html table rows which are selected by checkbox in php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

i have one html table which contain some coloumn like item name, item weight and item quantity.

i want to display those rows from table which are selected by checkbox. So i have created one coloumn for checkbox in each row.

can anybody tell me how to do above in php ?

please help me.

Comment: **AGAIN**. Luck you. I cannot flag your question today due to limit of flagging be reached. This is not kind of question here that we can answer for you. You need to tell us what is your specific problem, what have you tried, what result you expect.

Comment: Sir , my problem is that i want to display those rows from one html table which are selected by checkbox in php ?

Comment: Oh My JEHOVAH. This is not a problem. You wanna someone _do homework for you_, but we are not here for this. If you have any problem, post the code that has an issue, describe it, show us what have you tried and then what you expect from this code. You need to know how to ask here in SO.

Comment: I have following code :

    <form action="process.php">
    <table> 
      <?php while($v=mysql_fetch_array($res_item))
     {
             
     ?>
    <tr>
               <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?= $v['itemid'];?name="check_list[]"
    style="width:50px;height:50px;"/></td>
         <td><font size="5px"><b><?= $v['gname'] ?></b></td>
               <td><font size="5px"><b><?= $v['price'] ?></b></td>
               <td><font size="5px"><b><?= $v['weight'] ?></b></td>
             
     </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can do a search before posting your question, both for the sake of stackoverflow and ur own good.

2nd: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array) is your question asked before.

3rd: a quick guide to your problem :

1. Name all the check boxes in same group like

   < input type = "checkbox" name = "group[]" >
2. You can access them using

   print_r($_POST['group'] ;