# Checkbox in html

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have these group of checkboxes

upon submit .. i want to echo the chosen checkboxes in another page (pay.php)

for example: if I chose park and wash  .. in the pay.php page i want to echo park and wash BUT I only get wash (the last chosen checkbox) so how to make all chosen checkboxes printed??

```
 <form name="input" action="pay.php" method="post">
Services:
         <br/> 

        <input type="checkbox" name="service" value="park" checked>Park Only <br/> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="service" value="wash">Wash <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service" value="Check tires">Check Tires <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service" value="Fill oil">Fill Oil <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service" value="Check brakes">Check Brakes <br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Go to Paying" />
    </form>
```

IN PAY.php:

```
<?php


//$servicetext=$_POST["service"];
// echo $servicetext;
     ////THE ARRAY PART////

 echo "<table border='0'>
    <tr>
    <th> //PRINT THE ARRAY HERE </th>
    <th>  </th>
    <th>  </th>
    <th>  </th>
    <th>  </th>
<tr/>";

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Multiple Checkbox Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the check boxes are multiple you need to create an array of name for that same name of that input type.

```
 <form name="input" action="pay.php" method="post">
    Services:
             <br/> 

        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="park" checked>Park Only <br/> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="wash">Wash <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Check tires">Check Tires <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Fill oil">Fill Oil <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Check brakes">Check Brakes <br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Go to Paying" />
    </form>
```

in PAY.PHP, you can access each check box value in the below formats

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['service'])) {
    foreach($_POST['service'] as $service) {
          echo  $service;
         //rest of your code
    }
}
```

**Edited**

in PAY.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['service'])) {

$i = 0;
$selArr = array(); //i took an array that will store all these check box values
    foreach($_POST['service'] as $service) {
         $selArr[$i] = $service;
         $i++;
    }
}
```

**Edited2**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['service'])) {

$i = 0;
$selArr = array(); //i took an array that will store all these check box values
?>
<table>
        <?php 
         foreach($_POST['service'] as $key=>$service) {
         ?>

         <tr><td><?php echo $key; ?></td><td><?php echo $service; ?></td></tr>
         <?php
        }
            ?>
</table>

    <?php
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: @Sourbah do you have a way to save then in an array then print that array?? seems like your way may work

Comment: @CodeX, i added the code for storing in array in the edited part.

Comment: @Sourbah it's just that now you have an array but I can not put the function to be outputed in the form .. please check the edit above to understand better .. thanks alot by the way!!

Comment: @CodeX, i did not actually understand what are you trying to implement, if you are talking about passing that array in a function as parameter then after the foreach() loop is completed, you can pass that array as a normal parameter.

Comment: I have a service page and pay page .. In the service: you choose from check boxes and enter other data in textboxes then click submit button to go to pay.php ... In the pay: you get a table of the data you entered (like a receipt ) then you click pay .... so now we got the checkboxes as an array .. I want to print them in their place of the table@Sourabh

Comment: @CodeX, please check the edited2 in the answer i hope that helps, it might not be exact result table that you want, but you can modify it as i have created the structure.

Comment: @Sourbah i have a question in php again , if you have the time plz check it.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the checkbox values into array and then access all the posted values via this array:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="input" action="pay.php" method="post">
Services:
         <br/> 

        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="park" checked>Park Only <br/> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="wash">Wash <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Check tires">Check Tires <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Fill oil">Fill Oil <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Check brakes">Check Brakes <br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Go to Paying" />
    </form>
```

**PHP:**

Now all posted values are stored in `$service[]` array.

```
<?php
$servicetext=$_POST["service"];
var_dump($servicetext); // show all the posted values (content of posted array)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the checkbox name as an array as like this `service[]`

Modify your form as like below :

```
<form name="input" action="pay.php" method="post">
Services:
         <br/> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="park" checked>Park Only <br/> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="wash">Wash <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Check tires">Check Tires <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Fill oil">Fill Oil <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Check brakes">Check Brakes <br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Go to Paying" />
    </form>
```

Comment: it echos the word array .. @Jenis Patel

Comment: just try to check array as like this => `print_r($_POST["service"]);`