# Contact us html checkbox forum

Tags: php, html, css

I have a simple html contact us with a dropbox which allows me to select 1 of the many sellections and it sends to my email but i want it so i can select more than 1 option if possible. ill include html and the contact us php

the csss

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#skills  {
color:F0F8FF;
}

.about {
  margin: 70px auto 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 260px;
  font: 10px/18px 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #bbb;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #383838;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.about a {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background 0.1s;
  transition: background 0.1s;
}
.about a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #555;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.about-links {
  height: 30px;
}
.about-links > a {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.about-author {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.about-author > a {
  padding: 1px 3px;
  margin: 0 -1px;
}

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Thibaut Courouble
 * http://www.cssflow.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT License:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #879fa6 !important;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #879fa6;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #879fa6 !important;
}

body {
  font: 12px/20px 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background: #e4ecef;
}

input, textarea, select, label {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 320px;
  background: #eef5f7;
  border: 1px solid #cfd5da;
  border-bottom-color: #ccd1d6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.contact-inner {
  padding: 25px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.contact:before, .contact:after, .contact-inner:before, .contact-inner:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border: outset transparent;
  border-width: 12px 14px 0;
  border-top-style: solid;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.contact:before {
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-top-color: #d8e1e6;
}

.contact-inner:before {
  border-top-color: #ccd1d6;
}

.contact-inner:after {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top-color: #eef5f7;
}

.contact:after {
  margin-top: -8px;
  border-top-color: white;
}

.contact-input {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #eef7f9;
  border-radius: %px;
}
.contact-input > input, .contact-input > textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 29px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  color: #4d5a5e;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #cfdfe3;
  border-bottom-color: #d2e2e7;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.contact-input > input:focus, .contact-input > textarea:focus {
  border-color: #93c2ec;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #e1ecf5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #e1ecf5;
}
.lt-ie9 .contact-input > input, .lt-ie9 .contact-input > textarea {
  line-height: 27px;
}
.contact-input > textarea {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 20px;
  resize: none;
}

#email {
    color:purple; /*target element with id email and set text color to blue*/
}
#name {
    color: purple; /*target element with id name and set text color to red*/
}
#skype {
    color: purple; /*target element with id skype and set text color to green*/
}
#skills {
    color: purple; /*target element with id why and set text color to orange. in this case, its a select, so all the text within the select - meaning the options text- is orange*/
}
#participate  {
    color: purple;    /*target elements with class yellow (options) inside element id participate (select)  and set text color to yellow. in this case, you can select which options to make yellow by adding classes*/
}
#interested  {
    color: purple;    /*target elements with class yellow (options) inside element id participate (select)  and set text color to yellow. in this case, you can select which options to make yellow by adding classes*/
}
#message {
    color: purple; /*target element with id message and set text color to purple*/
}
#findus {
    color: purple; /*target element with id message and set text color to purple*/
}

.select {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #d2e2e7;
  border-bottom-color: #c5d4d9;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfdff, #f2f7f7);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfdff, #f2f7f7);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfdff, #f2f7f7);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfdff, #f2f7f7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}
.select:before, .select:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 11px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 3px outset transparent;
  border-right: 3px outset transparent;
}
.select:before {
  top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #7f9298;
}
.select:after {
  top: 16px;
  border-top: 3px solid #7f9298;
}
.select > select {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 112%;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 17px;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  padding-right: 0;
  color: #80989f;
  background: transparent;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.select > select:focus {
  color: #4d5a5e;
  outline: 0;
}

.contact-submit {
  text-align: right;
}
.contact-submit > input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 14px;
  height: 29px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #729fb2;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background: #deeef4;
  border: 1px solid #bed6e3;
  border-bottom-color: #accbd9;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e6f2f7, #d0e6ee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e6f2f7, #d0e6ee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e6f2f7, #d0e6ee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e6f2f7, #d0e6ee);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 0 0 4px #eef7f9;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 0 0 4px #eef7f9;
}
.contact-submit > input:active {
  color: #6a95a9;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  background: #c9dfe9;
  border-color: #a3bed0 #b5ccda #b5ccda;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 0 0 4px #eef7f9;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 0 0 4px #eef7f9;
}


<form name="enq" method="post" action="email/" onsubmit="return validation();">
    <fieldset class="contact-inner">
      <p class="contact-input">
        <input type="text" id="email" value="Your Email.." name="email" placeholder="Your Email..." autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="name" value="Your Full Name" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name." autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="skype" value="Your Skype Name" name="skype" placeholder="Your Skype Name." autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="findus" value="How Did You Find Us" name="findus" placeholder="How did you find us." autofocus>
      </p>

      <div id="skills">
      <p class="contact-input">
        <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="skills" id="skills">      
            <option value="" selected>Skills</option>
            <option value="3D Printing">3D Printing</option>
            <option value="Alternative Healers">Alternative Healers</option>
            <option value="Aquaponics/Hydroponics">Aquaponics/Hydroponics</option>
            <option value="Architecture/Design">Architecture/Design</option>
            <option value="Cabinetry / Carpentry">Cabinetry / Carpentry</option>
            <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
            <option value="Culinary Arts">Culinary Arts</option>
            <option value="Electrician">Electrician</option>
            <option value="EM Technology">EM Technology</option>
            <option value="Free Energy/QEG">Free Energy/QEG</option>
            <option value="Hair and/or Nail Stylist">Hair and/or Nail Stylist</option>
            <option value="Hemp Farming">Hemp Farming</option>
            <option value="Hempcrete">Hempcrete</option>
            <option value="Kundalini8 Practitioner">Kundalini8 Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Landscaping">Landscaping</option>
            <option value="Massage Therapist">Massage Therapist</option>
            <option value="Qi Gong Practitioners">Qi Gong Practitioners</option>
            <option value="Permaculture">Permaculture</option>
            <option value="Recycling">Recycling</option>
            <option value="Sewing">Sewing</option>
            <option value="Tai Chi Practitioner">Tai Chi Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>

          </select>
          <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="participate" id="participate">
            <option value="" selected>When can you participate?</option>
            <option value="3-6 months from now">3-6 months from now</option>
            <option class="purple" value="6-12 months">6-12 months</option>
            <option value="Next Year (2016)">Next Year (2016)</option>
            <option class="purple" value="Community Crowd Funding">Community Crowd Funding</option>
          </select>

          </select>
          <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="interested" id="interested">
            <option value="" selected>I'm interested in</option>
            <option value="Include me on Visionary Circle">Include me on Visionary Circle</option>
            <option class="purple" value="Can Travel">Can Travel</option>
            <option value="Benefactor">Benefactor</option>
            <option class="purple" value="Community Crowd Funding">Community Crowd Funding</option>
            <option value="Financial Contributor">Financial Contributor</option>
            <option value="Have a similar project">Have a similar project</option>
            <option value="Special Interest">Special Interest</option>
            <option value="Skilled">Skilled</option>
            <option value="Skype Chat">Skype Chat</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>

          </select>
        </label>
      </p>

      <p class="contact-input">
        <textarea rows="11" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message…">Your Message…</textarea>
      </p>

      <p class="contact-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull-right" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
        $skills = $_POST['skills'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $participate = $_POST['participate'];
    $interested = $_POST['interested'];
    $skype = $_POST['skype'];
    $findus = $_POST['findus'];
    $query = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';

 $to="";
 $subject="Contact Form PurpleParadise!";
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: ".$email_from."\r\n";
 $message="   

         skills:
         $skills
         <br>
         Email-Id:
         $email
         <br>        
         name:
         $name
         <br>
         participate:
         $participate
         <br>
         interested:
         $interested 
         <br>
         findus:
         $findus         
         <br>
         Message:
         $query        

   ";
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
        header("Location:../contact-us.html?msg=Successful Submission! Thankyou for contacting us.");
    else
        header("Location:../contact-us.html?msg=Error To send Email !");
        //contact:-your-email@your-domain.com
 }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to search before post your question? It's a good start to check if somebody already had the same problem before. There is something similar to what you're trying to do here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array

Comment: That's nice. But did you have a programming question?. This site is for questions, not "I want...(you to do my job for me)" to-do list dumping

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- add `multiple` attribute to the `select`
- change names to arrays like `name="skills"` to `name="skills[]"`

> use Ctrl+Select to select multiple options

```
    <form name="enq" method="post" action="email/" onsubmit="return validation();">
    <fieldset class="contact-inner">
      <p class="contact-input">
        <input type="text" id="email" value="Your Email.." name="email" placeholder="Your Email..." autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="name" value="Your Full Name" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name." autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="skype" value="Your Skype Name" name="skype" placeholder="Your Skype Name." autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="findus" value="How Did You Find Us" name="findus" placeholder="How did you find us." autofocus>
      </p>

      <div id="skills">
      <p class="contact-input">
        <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="skills[]" id="skills" multiple="multiple">      
            <option value="" selected>Skills</option>
            <option value="3D Printing">3D Printing</option>
            <option value="Alternative Healers">Alternative Healers</option>
            <option value="Aquaponics/Hydroponics">Aquaponics/Hydroponics</option>
            <option value="Architecture/Design">Architecture/Design</option>
            <option value="Cabinetry / Carpentry">Cabinetry / Carpentry</option>
            <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
            <option value="Culinary Arts">Culinary Arts</option>
            <option value="Electrician">Electrician</option>
            <option value="EM Technology">EM Technology</option>
            <option value="Free Energy/QEG">Free Energy/QEG</option>
            <option value="Hair and/or Nail Stylist">Hair and/or Nail Stylist</option>
            <option value="Hemp Farming">Hemp Farming</option>
            <option value="Hempcrete">Hempcrete</option>
            <option value="Kundalini8 Practitioner">Kundalini8 Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Landscaping">Landscaping</option>
            <option value="Massage Therapist">Massage Therapist</option>
            <option value="Qi Gong Practitioners">Qi Gong Practitioners</option>
            <option value="Permaculture">Permaculture</option>
            <option value="Recycling">Recycling</option>
            <option value="Sewing">Sewing</option>
            <option value="Tai Chi Practitioner">Tai Chi Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>

          </select>
          <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="participate[]" id="participate" multiple>
            <option value="" selected>When can you participate?</option>
            <option value="3-6 months from now">3-6 months from now</option>
            <option class="purple" value="6-12 months">6-12 months</option>
            <option value="Next Year (2016)">Next Year (2016)</option>
            <option class="purple" value="Community Crowd Funding">Community Crowd Funding</option>
          </select>

          </select>
          <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="interested[]" id="interested" multiple>
            <option value="" selected>I'm interested in</option>
            <option value="Include me on Visionary Circle">Include me on Visionary Circle</option>
            <option class="purple" value="Can Travel">Can Travel</option>
            <option value="Benefactor">Benefactor</option>
            <option class="purple" value="Community Crowd Funding">Community Crowd Funding</option>
            <option value="Financial Contributor">Financial Contributor</option>
            <option value="Have a similar project">Have a similar project</option>
            <option value="Special Interest">Special Interest</option>
            <option value="Skilled">Skilled</option>
            <option value="Skype Chat">Skype Chat</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>

          </select>
        </label>
      </p>

      <p class="contact-input">
        <textarea rows="11" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message…">Your Message…</textarea>
      </p>

      <p class="contact-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull-right" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Bring the following changes to the php content. To convert arrays to strings for processing, using comma as the separator

```
//change  $skills = $_POST['skills']; to 
$skills = implode(",", $_POST['skills']); 
//change   $participate = $_POST['participate'];
$participate = implode(",", $_POST['participate']);
//change  $interested = $_POST['interested'];
$interested = implode(",", $_POST['interested']);
```

**Always remember to sanitize user input accordingly**

here is the whole test.php file

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    //for debugging
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    $skills = implode(",", $_POST['skills']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $participate = implode(",", $_POST['participate'])?:"";
    $interested = implode(",", $_POST['interested'])?:"";
    $skype = $_POST['skype'];
    $findus = $_POST['findus'];
    $query = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';

 $to="";
 $subject="Contact Form PurpleParadise!";
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: ".$email_from."\r\n";
 $message="   

         skills:
         $skills
         <br>
         Email-Id:
         $email
         <br>        
         name:
         $name
         <br>
         participate:
         $participate
         <br>
         interested:
         $interested 
         <br>
         findus:
         $findus         
         <br>
         Message:
         $query        

   ";
   echo $message;
  //commented for debugging uncomment to use
  // if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
      //  header("Location:../contact-us.html?msg=Successful Submission! Thankyou for contacting us.");
    //else
      // header("Location:../contact-us.html?msg=Error To send Email !");
        //contact:-your-email@your-domain.com */
 }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="enq" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset class="contact-inner">
      <p class="contact-input">
        <input type="text" id="email" value="" name="email" placeholder="Your Email..." autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="name" value="" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name." autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="skype" value="" name="skype" placeholder="Your Skype Name." autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="findus" value="" name="findus" placeholder="How did you find us." autofocus>
      </p>

      <div id="skills">
      <p class="contact-input">
        <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="skills[]" id="skills" multiple="multiple">      
            <option value="" selected>Skills</option>
            <option value="3D Printing">3D Printing</option>
            <option value="Alternative Healers">Alternative Healers</option>
            <option value="Aquaponics/Hydroponics">Aquaponics/Hydroponics</option>
            <option value="Architecture/Design">Architecture/Design</option>
            <option value="Cabinetry / Carpentry">Cabinetry / Carpentry</option>
            <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
            <option value="Culinary Arts">Culinary Arts</option>
            <option value="Electrician">Electrician</option>
            <option value="EM Technology">EM Technology</option>
            <option value="Free Energy/QEG">Free Energy/QEG</option>
            <option value="Hair and/or Nail Stylist">Hair and/or Nail Stylist</option>
            <option value="Hemp Farming">Hemp Farming</option>
            <option value="Hempcrete">Hempcrete</option>
            <option value="Kundalini8 Practitioner">Kundalini8 Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Landscaping">Landscaping</option>
            <option value="Massage Therapist">Massage Therapist</option>
            <option value="Qi Gong Practitioners">Qi Gong Practitioners</option>
            <option value="Permaculture">Permaculture</option>
            <option value="Recycling">Recycling</option>
            <option value="Sewing">Sewing</option>
            <option value="Tai Chi Practitioner">Tai Chi Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>

          </select>
          <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="participate[]" id="participate" multiple>
            <option value="" selected>When can you participate?</option>
            <option value="3-6 months from now">3-6 months from now</option>
            <option class="purple" value="6-12 months">6-12 months</option>
            <option value="Next Year (2016)">Next Year (2016)</option>
            <option class="purple" value="Community Crowd Funding">Community Crowd Funding</option>
          </select>

          </select>
          <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="interested[]" id="interested" multiple>
            <option value="" selected>I'm interested in</option>
            <option value="Include me on Visionary Circle">Include me on Visionary Circle</option>
            <option class="purple" value="Can Travel">Can Travel</option>
            <option value="Benefactor">Benefactor</option>
            <option class="purple" value="Community Crowd Funding">Community Crowd Funding</option>
            <option value="Financial Contributor">Financial Contributor</option>
            <option value="Have a similar project">Have a similar project</option>
            <option value="Special Interest">Special Interest</option>
            <option value="Skilled">Skilled</option>
            <option value="Skype Chat">Skype Chat</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>

          </select>
        </label>
      </p>

      <p class="contact-input">
        <textarea rows="11" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message…"> </textarea>
      </p>

      <p class="contact-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull-right" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't understand why it was down voted :/ . i think its appropriate to comment a reason for down voting.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping i'm not sure who down voted they stupid ill try this now.

Comment: Hi i copy your html and it has a bug the drop down is overlapping i cant post an image do you have skype? so i can send the image would be much easier thanks.

Comment: @LinuxUnix if it works please mark this answer as correct, else let me know. i have already tested and works fine for me :)

Comment: @LinuxUnix now copy paste it.. it will work..or should i post whole page?

Comment: it overlapping pls add me on skype ill show you daz.holmes2 ill send a pic.

Comment: i don't use skype, i use viber, fb, twitter

Comment: @LinuxUnix copy paste the file i provided in the edited answer and save as test.php and check whether it works as you wish.

Comment: I using HTML and CSS which I didn't provide that maybe why ... Do you have email I'll pm full code and you will see

Comment: @LinuxUnix oh i thought so. so what to do now? i hope i solved this question for you now :) so Style part would be able after seeing the CSS.

Comment: @LinuxUnix if this solves your answer please accept the answer as correct. :)

Comment: this doesn't answer the question check the top i have edited the original message.