# Want to change action of form only when 1 checkbox is selected in the form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, checkbox

I want to submit the form and go to the action url only if one checkbox is selected.For that I used javascript as well as php. But it's not working properly.Once I select only one checkbox and preceed after that if I go back to the same page with the given code and go for the edit option again, it is not keeping a check if more than 1 or no checkbox is checked.
**I'm not using checkboxes because for the same form i've a delete button which can delete multiple enteries at one time**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" name="Edit"  value="Edit" />
```

JavaScript

```
<script language=Javascript>    
function changeaction()
{document.form1.action='4a2edit.php';}
</script>
```

Php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Edit'])){
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
if(count($_POST['checkbox'])>1)
{
echo"<br> <Font color=red> ***More than 1 checkbox selected.Make sure that only one checkbox must be selected.***</Font>";
}
else if (count($_POST['checkbox'])==0)
{
echo"<br><Font color=red> ***No checkbox is selected.***</Font>";
}   
else
{
echo "<script language=Javascript>  
changeaction();
</script>";
}}
?>
```

Sorry, the missing code is :

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<?php
//Some php code
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=".$row['ID']."> ".$row['ID'];
}
?>

<input type="submit" name="Edit"  value="Edit" />
```

Comment: where is checkbox in html? You should validate using javascript

Comment: sorry, i feel uneasy. anyway, to clarify your question we need your html code for your checkboxes. As <input type="checkbox" name="somename"> won't send the information as array. But <input type="checkbox" name="somename[]"> will send the entire checked checkboxes values. It's explained well in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array). As for validation, i believe you should keep server-side validatation, you won't know when *user* will throw input not from your form.

Comment: If you want someone to select exactly one of a set why are you using checkboxes in the first place? Checkboxes are designed for the state zero or more. Radio buttons are designed for the Exactly 1 state.

Comment: But Quentin I'm also using a delete button on the same page which can delete multiple enteries at a time.