# How can names in an echoed html tags be used

Tags: php, html

I have a code like this abc.php
I want to create an array of check boxes but if I try accessing the name or the id, it doesn't seem to work.Is there any alternative way to do this?

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <form method="post">
  <?php
 echo ""."<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id='check[]' />"
 $c=0;

     if(isset($_POST['check[$c]'])){
     echo "checked";
      }
   ?>
 </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the `foreach()` loop, [read about it here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: You have a syntax error, `echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id='check[]' />";`

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `$_POST['check[$c]']` in single quotes, it will not be replaced with the value of `$c`. Not to mention that multidimensional arrays do not work this way.

To check that $_POST variable treat it as an array:

```
$checked = $_POST['check'];
// $checked[0] - first element
// $checked[1] - second etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a base code, also you can split the php code from the html.
The foreach is better because now you know how what values the user actually submitted in a fast and easy way.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(isset($_POST['check']) && is_array($_POST['check'])){
            foreach($_POST['check'] as $key => $value){
                echo "$key => $value<br>"; # wrap this around single quotes ', see the difference.
            }
        }
    }

?>
<html>
 <body>
     <form method="post">
        <input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value="a">a</input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value="b">b</input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value="c">c</input>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value="d">d</input>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' />
     </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use arra, simply use variable like `if(isset($_POST['check']))`. If you want to display the value of checkbox then use `$_POST['check'][0]`.

```
 <form method="post">

 <?php
 echo ""."<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' id='check[]' value='test' />";
 echo "<input type='submit' />";

     if(isset($_POST['check'])){
         echo "checked";
      }
 ?>

 </form>
```