# Checkbox in a while loop php

Tags: php, html

I have a check box inside a while loop like this:

```
 <form method="POST">
    <?php $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE `id` ='$id' ");

     while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id_names" value="<? echo $get ['id'];?>"><?php echo $get ['name']; ?>
    <?php } ?>
   <input id="submitbtn"  type="submit" value="Submit" /><br><br>
</form>
```

The problem is at this part I am unable to get specific checkbox properties and even if the user selects two `check boxes` I am unable to echo the `id` out

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['id_names']))
        {
         $id_names= $_POST['id_names'];
         $email = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM users WHERE `id` = '$id_names'  ");
  while ($getemail = mysql_fetch_array($email))
      {
        echo $getemail['email'];
      }
         }
    ?>
```

I have tried searching for answers but I am unable to understand them. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: you can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array

Answer (score 0):

The form name `name="id_names"` needs to be an array to allow the parameter to carry more than one value: `name="id_names[]"`.

`$_POST['id_names']` will now be an array of all the posted values.

Comment: how can we differentiate that array suppose, I get `$_POST['id_name'] = 'add_2,add_3,add_4,add_5'`, so how can I get different different.

Answer (score 0):

Here your input field is multiple so you have to use name attribute as a array:

> FYI: You are using mysql that is deprecated you should use mysqli/pdo.

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
    <?php $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE `id` =$id ");

    while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="id_names[]" value="<?php echo $get['id'];?>"><?php echo $get['name']; ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="id_names[]" value="<?php echo $get['id'];?>"><?php echo $get['name']; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <input id="submitbtn"  type="submit" value="Submit" /><br><br>
</form>
```

**Form action: test.php (If your query is okay.)**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['id_names'])){
        foreach ($_POST['id_names'] as $id) {
            $email = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM users WHERE `id` = $id");
            $getemail = mysql_fetch_array($email); //Here always data will single so no need while loop
            print_r($getemail); 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Check it now @AshneelChand.

Comment: so the ` $id` is stored as numbers right
so when i do `WHERE id = $id ` it will say WHERE  id = '1' `
but it should be somthing like `WHERE id = jack `

Comment: Yes id is a integer, and  no need to use Quotation.