# PHP: calculate total price according to which options a user chooses from HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to create a PHP summary page for when a user submits an HTML form.

[image: image of the HTML form].

The form contains different options for hotel rooms. The HTML contains two **radio** buttons (single or double room) and **checkboxes** (if a guest wants to include Friday/Saturday/Sunday dinner).

Each of these options is associated to a different price: a single room is $80, a double is $60, and each meal is $8.

As of now I've succeeded in displaying the chosen options on the PHP form.

[image: Here is an image of an example PHP summary page.].

But I'm struggling to **calculate** and then **display** the total price **as a function of which options the guest has selected.**

Is there a good way to do this? Something tells me I might need to use arrays, but I haven't figured out how.

In case you wanted to take a look at the **HTML Code**:

```
<form action="ski-trip-summary.php" method="post">
<table id="mainTable">
<tr>
  <td class="mainSection"><b>Housing and Meals:</b><br />
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><i>Room Choices</i><br />
            <input name="room" type="radio" value="single" /> 
              Single ($80)
            <input name="room" type="radio" value="double" checked="checked" />
              Double ($40) </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><i>Meals desired ($8 each):</i><br />
            <table>
              <tr><td>Friday Dinner</td>   
                  <td><input name="fridayDinner" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
              <tr><td>Saturday Dinner</td> 
                  <td><input name="saturdayDinner" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
              <tr><td>Sunday Dinner</td>   
                  <td><input name="sundayDinner" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
            </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

and the **PHP code**:

```
print 'You have signed up for a ';
if ($_POST['room'] == 'single') {
print 'single room.';
} elseif ($_POST['room'] == 'double') {
print 'double room. <br /> <br />' ;
}

print 'Your meal signups are: <br />';

if (isset($_POST['fridayDinner']) && isset($_POST['saturdayDinner']) && isset ($_POST['sundayDinner'])) {
print '<i>Friday dinner <br />' . 'Saturday dinner <br />' . 'Sunday dinner </i>  <br />';

} elseif (isset($_POST['fridayDinner']) && isset($_POST['saturdayDinner'])) {
print '<i>Saturday dinner <br />' . 'Sunday dinner </i>  <br />';

} elseif (isset($_POST['fridayDinner']) && isset($_POST['sundayDinner'])) {
print '<i>Friday dinner <br />' . 'Sunday dinner </i>  <br />';

} elseif (isset($_POST['saturdayDinner']) && isset($_POST['sundayDinner'])) {
print '<i>Saturday dinner <br />' . 'Sunday dinner </i>  <br />';

} elseif (isset($_POST['saturdayDinner']) && isset($_POST['sundayDinner'])) {
print '<i>Saturday dinner <br />' . 'Sunday dinner </i>  <br />';

} else {
print '<i>No meals </i>  <br /><br />';

}
```

Thanks so much, and I appreciate any input or suggestions on how to do this better/more elegantly!

Comment: will not solve problem, but your dinner checkbox inputs should have the same name, but different values. and dont forget to use `[]` after the name so it will be an array. `<input name="dinner[]" type="checkbox" value="friday" />`

Comment: Assign variables to each POST array for integers and then add them up with `+`'s - while assigning one variable for them, and concatenating it with the *"Your total is..."*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you’re almost there! The tricky part is the checkboxes: a good way of solving this is using an array to store the output of the checkboxes. You can  see a similar solution here : [PHP Multiple Checkbox Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array) .

To make the dinner variable be returned as an array, make sure to add `[]`to the `name` field of the HTML form. You should have something like this:

```
<input name="dinner[]" type="checkbox" value="Friday" />  
<input name="dinner[]" type="checkbox" value="Saturday" />  
<input name="dinner[]" type="checkbox" value="Sunday" />
```

Then in your PHP,

```
$roomtype = $_POST['room']
print 'You have signed up for a ';
if ($roomtype == 'single') {
    $roomcost = 80;
    print 'Single room selected <br />';
} elseif ($roomtype == 'double') {
    $roomcost = 40;
    print 'Double room selected <br />';
}


$room = $_POST['room'];
$dinner = $_POST['dinner'];
$singleDinnerCost = 8;


if(isset($dinner)){
    // this part only makes sense if there are dinners selected. 
    // So we check for that in th line above
    // if no meals are checked, the dict will not exist
    print 'Your meal signups are: <br />';

    foreach ($dinner as $key => $day) { 
        print $day . ' dinner <br />';
    }

} else {
    // if no dinners are selected, the dinner dict will not even exit
    print 'You have not selected any dinners ! <br />'
}


if(isset($dinner)){
    // if there are dinners selected, count them
    $dinnerCount = count($dinner); 
} else {
    // if there are no selected dinners, set the dinner count to 0
    $dinnerCount = 0;
}

// compute total price
$total = $dinnerCount * $singleDinnerCost + $roomprice;

print 'Your total cost is $'.$total;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

your dinner checkbox inputs should have the same name, but different values. and dont forget to use `[]` after the name so it will be an array.

```
<input name="dinner[]" type="checkbox" value="friday" />  
<input name="dinner[]" type="checkbox" value="saturday" />  
<input name="dinner[]" type="checkbox" value="sunday" />
```

Then in the PHP code you can check how many dinners he selected and calculate total:

```
$total = 0;
$singleDinnerCost = 8;

if ($_POST['room'] == 'single') {
    $total = 80;
} elseif ($_POST['room'] == 'double') {
    $total = 40;
}


if(isset($_POST['dinner'])){
    $dinnerCount = count($_POST['dinner']); // $_POST['dinner'] is an array
    $total += $dinnerCount * $singleDinnerCost;
}

$echo 'Your total cost is $'.$total;
```

Note that this code is only to calculate total, not to print all the other strings. You can add that part yourself

Comment: I think you left out the very part OP was having trouble with, although I may have misunderstood.