# How to create a ecommerce filter with php using the GET method

Tags: php, html, json, get, e-commerce

I know there are better ways to do it, but I really need to create a multiple parameter filter with PHP only in order to filter items by from a json.

The categories are separated by Gender, type of Item, colors etc... I want to be able to select multiple categories, and if only gender is set to show all products, call them using the $_GET method and be able to filter using IFs.

The problem is that my amateur coding skills are not helping much, and I am also not sure if without AJAX there is a better way to do this.

This is what part of my filter looks like:

```html
<ul class="category-menu" name="categoria">         
    <li><a href="page.php?genid=<?php echo $genid;?>&cat=remeras&col=<?php echo ($_GET["col"]);?>&mar=<?php echo ($_GET["mar"]);?>" name="campera" >Remeras</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.php?genid=<?php echo $genid;?>&cat=camperas&col=<?php echo $col;?>&mar=<?php echo $mar;?>" name="campera">Camperas</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.php?genid=<?php echo $genid;?>&cat=pantalones&col=<?php echo $col;?>&mar=<?php echo $mar;?>" name="pantalones">Pantalones</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.php?genid=<?php echo $genid;?>&cat=shorts&col=<?php echo $col;?>&mar=<?php echo $mar;?>" name="short">Shorts</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.php?genid=<?php echo $genid;?>&cat=vestidos&col=<?php echo $col;?>&mar=<?php echo $mar;?>" name="vestido">Vestidos</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I have my ifs looking like this:

```html
<?php   

}elseif ( !empty($_GET["genid"]) && !empty($_GET["cat"]) && $datosArray[$i]["sex_id"] == $_GET["genid"] && $datosArray[$i]["categoria"] == $_GET["cat"]){

?>

<!-- Individual Product full Code -->  
...
<!-- /Individual Product full Code -->  

<?php   

    }elseif (!empty($_GET["genid"]) && $datosArray[$i]["sex_id"] == $_GET["genid"]){
?>

<!-- Individual Product full Code -->  
 ... 
<!-- /Individual Product full Code --> 

<?php 
    }} ?>
```

Right now the only "filter" it recognizes is the Gender one and its displaying all products even if the $_GET is set and displayed properly.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I turn your code into psuedo-code, it reads like this.

if we have the following: a `genid, cat`
and the `genid` is the same as `$datosArray[$i]["sex_id"]`
and the `datosArray[$i]["categoria"]` is the same as `$_GET["cat"]`
then display the product

Otherwise, if we have a `genid`
and that `genid` is the same as `$datosArray[$i]["sex_id"]`
then display the product

If that is what you where intending to have happen, then you might want to `var_dump` or `print_r` all of your variables, and make sure nothing unexpected is happening.

---

You talked about wanting to use multiple categories. There are two ways of doing this that I can think of right now. The first is to have a comma separated list of categories `href="...cat=pantelones,vestidos,shorts`, and then turn that into an array `$cats = explode(',', $_GET['cat'])`. You would then check for a specific category with `in_array('pantelones', $cats)`.

The second is to create an HTML form that uses a checkbox to select multiple categories, and then if you simply add brackets to the end of the checkbox's name, then when the user submits the form, PHP will automatically convert $_GET['cat'] into an array for you [See this SO question for more info about what I mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array).

---

I would do things more like this.

```
function display_product($productData){
    /* Add code here to display your product */
}

foreach($datosArray as $productData){

    /* Always display the product if the gender ID was not set */
    if ( empty($productData['genid']) ){
        display_product($productData);
    }

    /* Otherwise only display the product if it matches what is in $_GET[] */
    if (
        isset($_GET["genid"]) && $_GET["genid"] == $productData['sex_id']
        && isset($_GET["cat"]) && $_GET["cat"] == $productData['categoria']
        && isset($_GET["mar"]) && $_GET["mar"] == $productData['Marca']
    ){
        display_product($productData);
    }

}
```

---

I know you already said you knew that there where better ways of filtering data, I just want to add that once it comes time to add/edit/delete data, databases become super useful. They are also speedier at filtering out the data you want.

---

You introduced an XSS vulnerability. You should always escape your variables before outputting them, like so. (I like to use `<?=` which is just a shorthand for `<?php echo`.)

```
<ul class="category-menu" name="categoria">         
    <li><a href="page.php?genid=<?= (int)$genid ?>&cat=remeras&col=<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET["col"]) ?>&mar=<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET["mar"]) ?>" name="campera" >Remeras</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.php?genid=<?= (int)$genid ?>&cat=camperas&col=<?= htmlspecialchars($col) ?>&mar=<?= htmlspecialchars($mar) ?>" name="campera">Camperas</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.php?genid=<?= (int)$genid ?>&cat=pantalones&col=<?= htmlspecialchars($col) ?>&mar=<?= htmlspecialchars($mar) ?>" name="pantalones">Pantalones</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.php?genid=<?= (int)$genid ?>&cat=shorts&col=<?= htmlspecialchars($col) ?>&mar=<?= htmlspecialchars($mar) ?>" name="short">Shorts</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.php?genid=<?= (int)$genid ?>&cat=vestidos&col=<?= htmlspecialchars($col) ?>&mar=<?= htmlspecialchars($mar) ?>" name="vestido">Vestidos</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP offers a `http_build_query($arrayOrObject)` function which is useful on its own. Check the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

I made myself a tiny wrapper for the function that I normally use for such things.

```php
/**
 * Build query parameters string from given arrays ($_GET by default)
 * @param array $newGet
 * @param null|array $currentGet
 * @return string
 */
function new_build_query(array $newGet = [], ?array $currentGet = null)
{

    if (!isset($currentGet))
        $currentGet = $_GET;

    $newGet = array_merge($currentGet, $newGet);

    ksort($newGet);

    return http_build_query($newGet);
}
```

Given the current URL being `https://example.com/?page=2`his can be used like this:

```php
$params = new_build_query([
    'sort' => 'asc',
    'filter' => 'female',
]);
// $params === 'filter=female&page=2&sort=asc'
$redirectUrl = "https://example.com/?{$params}";
```

Answer (score -2):

your code is a bit confusing in the way it is displaying the results. So I mean you want to filter a product, from there the genre and following specific details such as color, size etc. on request by ajax is possible yes. but I advise to leave these parameters in database and from this make the filters. If you are based only on json use json_decode ($ data, true) to make it an array so you can do the filters more simply. I also advise using a template engine (twig for example) to separate php code from html. that would be better for you